# Determining all right-angled triangles with sides $a$, $a+k$ and $a+2k$

Tags: trigonometry

> Determine all triangles that are right-angled which has the sides:
>   $$a, \quad b = a+k, \quad c = a+2k.$$
>   (a, k are natural numbers!)

So does this mean I have to take a look at:

1. $a^2+b^2=c^2 \iff a^2-2ak-3k^2=0$
2. $b^2+c^2=a^2 \iff a^2+6ak+5k^2=0$
3. $a^2+c^2=b^2 \iff a^2+2ak+3k^2=0$

If so, I get (1.1) $a=3k$ (I did $f(a)=a^2-2ak-3k^2=0$)
in all other cases I get negative $k$ or negative $a$.

What's the best way to deal with this (I'll assume) simple task?

Answer (score 3):

As the sides are in Arithmetic Progression, it is better to take the sides to be $\displaystyle c-d,c,c+d$

So, we have  $\displaystyle  (c-d)^2+c^2=(c+d)^2\iff c^2=4cd\iff c=4d$ as $c\ne0$

Comment: ok that's simpler...

Comment: @draks..., thanks. If the number of terms in an A.P. is even unlike here we can set values as $$a\pm d,a\pm2d,a\pm nd$$ for $2n$ terms

Answer (score 2):

Since $a$ and $k$ are natural numbers you see that $c$ is always the longest side, so it will be the hypotenuse. Therefore, you can skip case 2. and 3. right away. Solving 1. won't get simpler as you've done it. And if simplicity is how you measure the best way, that's it, I would say...

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Sure, in fact
$$b^2+c^2=a^2 \iff a^2+6ak+5k^2=0$$ means $$ a = -k,  a = -5k$$
while
$$a^2+c^2=b^2 \iff a^2+2ak+3k^2=0$$ have a unique integer solution $$ a = k = 0.$$
So $$a^2+b^2=c^2 \iff a^2-2ak-3k^2=0$$ is the unique possible answer: $$ a = -k,  a = 3k.$$
Finally the sides of all the possible triangles are of the form $(3k,4k,5k)$, the simplest Pitagorean triple!